# How to pivot a pandas Dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to pivot the below dataframe. I want the column names to be added as rows. First row is a statis one but the Column names are not static since they will be calculated for the all numerical columns from the data frame. Could you please help.

This is my data frame:

[image]

Expected Dataframe:

[image]

Comment: What you're doing is not exactly a pivot; you are transposing the table.  There are already answers for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add .T :) df.describe().T to transpose  your results:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a Dictionary of series
d = {'Name':pd.Series(['Alisa','Bobby','Cathrine','Madonna','Rocky','Sebastian','Jaqluine',
   'Rahul','David','Andrew','Ajay','Teresa']),
   'Age':pd.Series([26,27,25,24,31,27,25,33,42,32,51,47]),
   'Score':pd.Series([89,87,67,55,47,72,76,79,44,92,99,69])}

#Create a DataFrame
pd.DataFrame(d).describe().T
```

Results:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can `transpose` the dataframe:

`data_pivot = data_pd.T`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

Answer (score 0):

Other way is `.transpose()`:

```
data_pivot = data_pd.transpose()
```